# Handling a function parameter that includes an apostrophe?

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a function that allows users to edit a name and submit their changes. The issue is if a user's name has an apostrophe, it will not trigger the function and returns an error message of: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

I have tried this:

```
let newName = service.toString().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''); 
let viewhtml = '<h2 style="text-align: center" id="serviceh2"><span id="servicename">'+service['name']+'</span> <i class="fa fa-pencil addPointer" onclick=editName(\''+newName['name']+'\',\''+id+'\');">`
```

This works, but when I inspect the element it really is "undefined". I can edit the name and submit a new name, but when I use the text field it says "undefined" while editing. I can remove that, but editing text with a blank text field I feel is bad practice and so is having the element really be undefined.

Here is the function to edit the name:

```
function editName(currentname, serviceid) {
    document.getElementById('serviceh2').innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="servicenameedit" value="'+currentname+'"><button type="button" onclick="submitEditName(\''+serviceid+'\');">Submit</button>'; 
}
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53303508/edit) your question, then click the snippet editor `[<>]` and provide a [mcve]

Comment: How about `document.getElementById('serviceh2').innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="servicenameedit" value="'+currentname+'"><button type="button" value="'+encodeURIComponent(serviceid)+'" onclick="submitEditName(this.value)">Submit</button>'; 
`

Comment: You should not build HTML fragments via string concatenation. Create the elements and then set their attributes via the DOM api.

Comment: Hmmm. That solution still gives me the uncaught syntax error I was experiencing earlier, and does not trigger the function